# Onomatopoeia for throat clearing

Tags: onomatopoeia

Clearing one's throat is a nice way to signal that special attention is needed. For example, two colleagues are making fun of their boss as she walks right by. She listens for a second and then ... clears her throat to say "I'm here".

- Is there an onomatopoeia for that?
- If not, how could that be expressed in writing?

Comment: Yes, but it's not onomatopoeic, except that _ahem_ has two syllables, and there are usually two chest pulses in an attention-getting throat-clearing event.

Comment: @JohnLawler... but isn't it the attempt that makes it onomatopoetic? I mean how good or bad it is is largely up to the person, considering that the onomatopoeia for a certain sound can vary quite a lot from language to language

Comment: Onomatopoeia is an attempt to imitate the sound; there's very little of that with _ahem_; you could just as easily say _cough, cough_.

Comment: @JohnLawler... so you're saying that "ahem" is not an attempt to imitate sound? What is it then? I think, it may not be a very successful o. but it is one all the same. As is "to cough" by the way

Comment: OK, if you say so. I don't care, particularly; it just seemed like a particularly stylized imitation, is all.

Comment: There's a reason we went to the trouble of defining words to mean things rather than imitating the sounds all the time.

Comment: When I listen to myself about the closest I can come is "cuhuhuhuh" or perhaps "cuhcuhcuhcuh".

Comment: @emanuel et al. Moo is onomatopoeic. That being said, onomatopoeia change sounds with language and culture. Thus, the onomatopoeia for the sound a chicken makes will be different in French than it is in English or Chinese.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Ahem*.

**exclamation**
1.
used to represent the noise made when clearing the throat, typically to attract attention or express disapproval or embarrassment.
"ahem, excuse me"

[Meaning.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ahem)

Comment: A question - an answer :)  Good one

Answer (score 0):

## Cough

This is the first word I'd think of, and it's onomatopoeic.

Answer (score 0):

In the immortal words of Dolores Umbridge:

> *Hem-hem*.

Answer (score 0):

Ahem is either but not both.
If Ahem is said "I say, ahem, I say" it is an exclamation.  This is equivalent to British "Hem hem!"
If ahem replaces the sound of the clearing of the throat in a sentence, it is onomatopoeic.